# ionic 2 ion-refresher always fired when pulling up after the on-refresh function triggered once

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, refresher

[Appearing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE3SC.png)

```
<ion-content class="orderFormHeader">
<ion-refresher (refresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
</ion-refresher>
<ion-list *ngIf="listData!=null&&listData.length>0">
    <ion-item *ngFor="#obj of listData">
        <orderitem [item]="obj"></orderitem>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

*My code above.*

At first,the `listData` is null, `doRefresh` will give more than 20 items into `listData`.
you can pulling down smoothly.

But when you pulling up back, it
**FAR FROM THE TOP**,

The `doRefresh` triggered, then the list jumpped to the TOP. You can't see any item mid of the list.

**Chrome console warn:**

> Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for
>   example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.

ionic CLI v2.0.0-beta.17

Comment: doRefresh(refresher){
    this.listData = [........];
    setTimeout(() => {
      refresher.complete();
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
    }, 1000);
  }

Comment: complete in the doRefresh() already.....

Answer (score 0):

im update ionic-framework to beta.2,the problem's gone~

```
    "ionic-framework": "2.0.0-beta.2"
```

thanks to my pro-matser

THIS IS WHAT HE GAVE ME:

**https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/milestones
Pull to refresh - bug fixes beta.2**

if anyone has this problem , plz UPDATE TO A UPPER VER~

Comment: same problem here.
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  }

Answer (score -1):

check the list data show on the refresh. when you pull to refresh and set the list to [] (empty). like myself here. set items to null and right after concat the item

[image]